# Reading the username and password inside .txt file

Tags: python

I'm having a trouble on what to do with these. I have `accounts.txt` file where users input will be transfer to the file. The problem is how to read the txt file to check the credentials.

These are the text inside .txt file:

```
carl,1234,10000
123,123,100000
```

This is the code:

```
listOfAccounts = open('accounts.txt', 'a')

newUsername = str(input("Enter NEW Username: "))
newPassword = str(input("Enter NEW Password: "))
newAmount = str(input("Enter your Deposit Amount: "))

listOfAccounts.write(newUsername + "," + newPassword + "," + newAmount)
listOfAccounts.write("\n.\n")

print("CONGRATS! Your Account has been created.")



loginUsername = input("Enter Username: ")
loginPassword = input("Enter PASSWORD: ")

with open('accounts.txt', 'r') as data:
    accounts = data.readlines()

for line in data:
    accounts = line.split(",")
    if loginUsername == accounts[0] and loginPassword == accounts[1]:
        print("LOGGED IN")
        break
    else:
        print("Login FAILED")
        break
```

By the way, the program needs to read all the info in file when the program starts (I already know how that works).

Comment: Pretty sure the conflict is in `accounts = data.readlines()` and `accounts = line.split(",")`

Comment: yah i think, i dont know what variables to add on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 issues:

1. You are overwriting the values stored in accounts
2. You are using the file handle `data` after the file has been closed
3. You never closed the first opening of the account file. Prevent this from happening by using the `with open(filename)` standard.

Note that [the answer from not_speshal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68006598/9267296) is the better solution. Dicts are extremely usefull

```py
def register():
    newUsername = str(input("Enter NEW Username: "))
    newPassword = str(input("Enter NEW Password: "))
    newAmount = str(input("Enter your Deposit Amount: "))

    #always use with open to make sure the file gets closed after you're done.
    with open(accountfile, 'a') as listOfAccounts:
        listOfAccounts.write(newUsername + "," + newPassword + "," + newAmount)
        # I would omit the line below, as you basically have a CSV file if you don't add the line below
        listOfAccounts.write("\n.\n")

    print("CONGRATS! Your Account has been created.")



def login():
    loginUsername = input("Enter Username: ")
    loginPassword = input("Enter PASSWORD: ")

    with open(accountfile) as data:
        accounts = data.readlines()

    userfound = False
    for line in accounts:
        splitline = line.split(",")
        if loginUsername == splitline[0] and loginPassword == splitline[1]:
            userfound = True
            break
    return userfound


userfound = login()
if userfound:        
    print("LOGGED IN")
else:
    print("Login FAILED")
```

Comment: sorry for the code, I'm not aware of the differences between "open" and "with open" since no one thought me of the diff. usage of the two. thanks for the help. I will try to replicate it using the  DICT as you two suggested :)

Comment: @EdoAske the problem is it doesnt read the new credentials inside, it only reads the first line of file

Comment: yeah my bad, the `else` statement you were using caused it to `break` when the username/password did not match the first line of the accounts file. I've edited my answer and updated the logic to use a function. I did the same for the registration logic.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of parsing line by line, you can save the `username` and `password` in a `dict` comprehension and just check if what the user entered is in the `dict`.
Something like this:

```
users = dict()
with open('accounts.txt', 'r') as data:
    users = {s.split(",")[0]: s.split(",")[1] for s in data.readlines()}

loginUsername = input("Enter Username: ")
loginPassword = input("Enter PASSWORD: ")
if users.get(loginUsername, None) == loginPassword:
    print("LOGGED IN")
else:
    print("Login failed")
```

Comment: i didnt think of it since i only know that dict has nothing to do with .txt file. thanks for this. I will study the use of it. :)